# Common rewrite rule to append query to all the defined rewrite rules in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect from old site urls to new site urls.
I have many rules in htaccess files.
See example below:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/one$ http://www.newsite.com/blog/x/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/two$ http://www.newsite.com/blog/y/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/three$ http://www.newsite.com/blog/z/ [R=301,L]
and so on..........
```

Redirection is working fine.
Now I want to append a query string **"?key=value&anotherKey=anotherValue"** to all the destination urls.
Is there a way to do this task by single line of code? 
Or do I need to append this query to all the urls one by one.

Here is an example that I want:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/one$ http:www.newsite.com/blog/x/?key=value&anotherKey=anotherValue [R=301,L]
```

EDITED:
complete htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Custom redirection Starts form here

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0?key=value&anotherKey=anotherValue [L,NC]

#home page redirection
RewriteRule ^$ http://newsite.com/ [R=301,L]

#Blog Rewrite Rules
RewriteRule     ^blog/this-blog-is-included-for-redirection/?$ http://newsite.com/blog/ [R=301,L]

#Custom redirection ends here


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I access this url:
oldsite.com/blog/this-blog-is-included-for-redirection/

it redirects to:
newsite.com/blog/?key=value&anotherKey=anotherValue

This is fine.

When I access this URL:
oldsite.com/blog/this-blog-is-exluded-for-redirection/

it redirects to:
oldsite.com/blog/this-blog-is-exluded-for-redirection/?key=value&anotherKey=anotherValue

Here I do not want to append the query.

Comment: rule is working. I want to append query string to all the destination url by one or few line of codes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can do it like this `http://www.newsite.com/blog/x/?param1=x&param2=y` `[R=301,L,QSA]`

Comment: Well instead of `^blog/one` you could have `/block/(.*)` to rewrite to `.../blog/$1?key=...` for all blogs. Problem being you have a redirect and not a rewrite so this may cause an infinite loop so you may need to refine the regex or add conditions

Comment: @SahilGulati there are hundred of lines in htaccess file. Pasting query params to all the urls one by one is not good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a generic rule before your redirect rules to set the query string and redirect rules will automatically carry over query string to target URIs:

```
RewriteEngine On

# generic rule for query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^blog/(?:one|two|three)/?$ $0?key=value&anotherKey=anotherValue [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^blog/one/?$ http://www.newsite.com/blog/x/ [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/two/?$ http://www.newsite.com/blog/y/ [R=301,L,nC]
RewriteRule ^blog/three/?$ http://www.newsite.com/blog/z/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: I just added R=301 In your rule i.e. RewriteRule ^blog/(?:one|two|three)/?$ $0?key=value&anotherKey=anotherValue [R=301,L,NC] now it is working fine. Before this, the url "oldsite.com/blog" was not working and the url "oldsite.com/blog/" and "oldsite.com/blog/anything" are only working. Can you please explain your answer a little bit? Can we use the generic rule anywhere in the htaccess file?

Comment: Sure. I have added just one generic rule. That rule checks if there is no query string and when that condition succeeds it adds a desired query string in some selected URIs defined by pattern `^blog/(?:one|two|three)/?$`. Due to this you next set of rules get that common query string already appended.

Comment: When it redirects to newsite.com, it appends query string which is fine, 
but I have excluded some urls from redirection and it appends query to that urls also.
How can I avoid to append query to oldsite.com

Comment: **I have excluded some urls from redirection**: Can you show full .htaccess in question to show how you have excluded those URLs. Also do you want to exclude all URLs of `oldsite.com` from this redirection?

Comment: I have updated my question. I do not want to exclude all URLs.

Comment: It is because you are using `RewriteRule ^.*$` in the rule that adds query string. Note that I have `RewriteRule ^blog/(?:one|two|three)/?$` instead to match specific URIs for which query string should be appended.

Comment: Right. 
In case if I have a blog at oldsite.com/blog/four which I do not want to redirect to newsite.com as well as do not want to append query.
Is there any way to do it? 
Currently I am appending query to each destination URL.

Comment: Yes you can use: `RewriteRule ^blog/(?:one|two|three)?/?$ $0?key=value&anotherKey=anotherValue [L,NC]` and it will skip `/blog/` also